# In Dockers Platform Spring flash attribute every time set NULL value

Tags: java, linux, spring

Deploying web app on dockers platform , Issue when using spring flash attribute from one controller to another controller attribute value always retrieve 'NULL' , even same web app when deploy on Linux server flash attribute have a specific set value. All app versions are (latest or stable) and same on every platform. Implement all provided methods like , RequestContextUtils , @ModleAttribute() , Model , ModelMap but fail in every case only in dockers.

Comment: I don't see how Docker can interfere with your String MVC application. Is this a Spring Boot application? What king of web server do you use?

Comment: Spring Boot application. Tomcat web server we use. Overall app deployed successfully and works fine but I'm totally surprised why flash attribute set null value.